# Битовые сдвиги С++

Tags: c++

Нужно выполнить путём сдвига вправо все биты, значение которых равно нулю и влево все биты, значение которых равно единице.

Подскажите, как это можно осуществить?

Comment: Посчитать и построить заново

Comment: Вопрос имеет странную формулировку, следует её скорректировать. Предполагаю что имеется ввиду подсчёт нулей слева и справа путём сдвига влево или вправо до единицы.

Comment: И что должно произойти с битом, у которого слева 0, а справа 1?

Comment: Про что вы тут? По мне задача понятна как сместить все единичные биты в старшие разряды, сохранив ширину. Разве нет? Отстортировать, так сказать, биты по убыванию =)

Comment: Нужно выполнить **что**?

Answer (score 1):

Это решение основано на том, что в вопросе не указан размер числа.
Поэтому все операции выполняются в рамках исходной ширины входного параметра.
Решение в рамках полной ширины переменной определённого типа проще и есть в соседних(напр. @Qwertiy) ответах.

```
unsigned solve(unsigned n) {
  int zeroes = 0;
  unsigned result = 0;
  while (n) {
      if (n&1) result = (result << 1) | 1; // Вдвигаем единицы
      else zeroes++; // Считаем нули
      n >>= 1;
  }
  result <<= zeroes; // Вдвигаем нули

  return result;
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << solve(1024) << std::endl; // 1024
  std::cout << solve(1025) << std::endl; // 1536 = 2^10+2^9
  // 10000000001 -> 11000000000
  std::cout << solve(682) << std::endl; // 992
  // 1010101010 -> 1111100000
  std::cout << solve(-1u) << std::endl; // 4294967295
  std::cout << solve(0) << std::endl; // 0

}
```

---

Или, с шаблонами, концептами и `<bit>`:

```
#include <bit>
#include <concepts>

template <std::unsigned_integral T>
T tsolve(const T& n, bool full_width = true) {
    T full_bits = ~T{0};
    if (n == full_bits || n == 0) {
        return n;
    }

    T t = full_bits;
    T shift = (T)(sizeof(T)*8 - std::popcount(n));

    if (full_width) {
        return t << shift; 
    }    

    t >>= shift;
    t <<= shift - std::countl_zero(n);

    return t;
}

#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout.setf(std::ios::hex, std::ios::basefield);
    std::cout << tsolve(uint32_t(1033)) << std::endl;          // e0000000
    std::cout << tsolve(uint16_t(1033)) << std::endl;          // e000

    std::cout << tsolve(uint32_t(1033), false) << std::endl;   // 700
}
```

Comment: Мне кажется, в таком варианте `(1 << ones)` вызовет переполнение когда все биты стоят. Еще единицы и нули незачем считать отдельно. А еще в новом стандарте есть `::std::popcount` с которым вообще [в одну строку](https://godbolt.org/z/x9h9P7), а раньше он был в виде интринсика.

Comment: Вы правда думаете, что popcount — именно то, что хотел увидеть в решении преподаватель? То-то вы за неуд переживали)) Вопрос с подсчётом значащих нулей остался открытым)

Comment: Сдвиг на всю ширину типа - неопределенное поведение даже у беззнаковых типов. И что то странное [выдает для двойки.](https://ideone.com/B8Ywkj)

Comment: Про UB  уговорили. Для двойки(10) ответ, как ни странно, двойка(10)

Comment: хм я думал ответ 1000_сколько_то_там_нулей_00, ну, может я и не прав, автор вопроса не уточнил

Comment: Зачем в цикле считатать **и нули и единицы???** (достаточно чего-то одного). При этом (если считать единицы) можно запросто в том же цикле сделать переменную с заданным числом единиц в старших разрядах.

Comment: Что ж вы все про одно и то же) Специально же примеры оставил десятиразрядные. @avp,  если их не считать, как мне сохранить ширину числа?

Comment: Может быть, я и понял задачу неверно, но решал я **именно её!!!** =)

Comment: 2 способ. Если n равен 0, то опять сдвиг на всю ширину типа.

Comment: Благодарю, починил)

Answer (score 1):

https://ideone.com/PfcFaC

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
 
int main()
{
  int x;
  scanf("%d", &x);
 
  int n = __builtin_popcount(x);
  printf("%08X", n ? ~0U << 32-n : 0);
 
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Запостю тогда уж свое решение на C++20 из комментария:

```
#include <bit>
#include <climits>
#include <cstdint>

[[nodiscard]] constexpr auto
bitsort(::std::uint32_t const value) noexcept
{
    if (value)
    {
        return (compl decltype(value){}) >> (sizeof(value) * CHAR_BIT - ::std::popcount(value));
    }
    else
    {
        return value;
    }
}

static_assert(0x00 == bitsort(0x00));
static_assert(0x01 == bitsort(0x01));
static_assert(0x01 == bitsort(0x02));
static_assert(0x01 == bitsort(0x02000000));
static_assert(0x03 == bitsort(0x102));
static_assert(0x03 == bitsort(0x01000001));
static_assert(0x00FFFFFF == bitsort(0xFF0FF0FF));
static_assert(0xFFFFFFFF == bitsort(0xFFFFFFFF));
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Y7KT51

Comment: nodiscard + constexpr + auto + ::std + noexcept + compl + decltype... пощадите автора вопроса :D

Comment: Вы не в ту сторону сортируете

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл Должен же он приложить хоть какие-то собственные усилия к этому заданию.

Comment: @vp_arth Почему не в ту? Я так понял, что влево - это в сторону меньших разрядов. При желании можно сортировать в противоположную сторону сменив `>>` на `<<`.

Comment: У вас младшие разряды слева.. неожиданно) Ну ок)

Comment: @vp_arth Ну так Big Endian - все-таки редкость.

Comment: BE так-то про байты, а не про биты)

Comment: @vp_arth Было бы странно считать порядок бит отличным от порядка байт. Ведь при сдвиге `>>` в сторону младших бит биты будут переходить в сторону младших разрядов и наоборот.

Comment: Хотите сказать, единичный байт на LE машине при передаче на BE машину интерпретируется как байт со значением 127? Кстати, поведение вашей функции не определено если передать ей ноль.

Comment: Почему сдвиг вправо сдвигает в сторону младших разрядов, если они слева?

Comment: @vp_arth Ну так это только стрелочка в операторе  `>>` вправо показывает, а сдвигает он в сторону младших разрядов, а если уж на Little Endian они слева, то и сдвиг получается влево, нет?

Comment: Ага, и в ассемблере и спеках процессоров оператор shr просто так назвали по совпадению

Comment: @vp_arth может это потому что в записи 0x00100000 бит окажется правее?

Comment: Вы, возможно. удивитесь, но при переходе BE->LE и наоборот 0x0001 становится 0x0100, а не 0x8000

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл Это интересный вопрос. По идее, если порядок бит в байте у них различается, то при обычных способах передачи (по сети там, или через диск) всегда имеется какой-то промежуточный протокол, в котором этот порядок явно задан. А так наверное действительно могло бы получаться, что биты не в тех разрядах оказываются.